# Decimal to Hex in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, character

I've coded this program to get a number and a base as two inputs, then prints the number in the given base, it does work well when the base is less than 10, but when I enter a base like 16, instead of printing the word "A" for 10, or F for 15, the program prints the ASCII value of the words, but I want the words themselves.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int base(int n, int t);

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do {
        int n=0, t=0;
        base(n,t);
        
        cout << "\n\nDo you want to continue?(y/n)";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch=='y');

}

int base(int n, int t)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter the number : ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the base : ";
    cin >> t;
    
    int i=80;
    int x[i];
    int m=n;
    

    for (i=1; n>=t ;i++) 
    {
        int rem;
        rem = n%t;
        n = n/t;


    if (rem>9)
    { 
        switch (char(rem)) 
        {
            case 10 :
                rem = 'A';
                break;
            case 11 :
                rem = 'B';
                break;
            case 12 :
                rem = 'C';
                break;
            case 13 :
                rem = 'D';
                break;
            case 14 :
                rem = 'E';
                break;
            case 15 :
                rem = 'F';
                break;
        }
    } 
    

    x[i]=rem;
    }
    

    cout << "The number " << m << " in base " << t << " is = ";
    cout << n;
            

    for (int j=(i-1); j>0; j--)
        cout << x[j];
        

    return 0;

}
```

I know it's because I have declared x[i] as an integer, so that's why it's happening, but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: `cout << (char)x[j]` or declare `x` as an array of `char` instead of integers. Note that either way, variable-length arrays are non-standard C++. Use a `const` value or literal for your array size. Or use a dynamic container such as `std::vector` or even `std::string`.

Comment: Also there is no need for `base` to get `n` and `t` as parameters. They can be local variables in the function.

Comment: @wohlstad you mean it's better to declare "base" as void?

Comment: `int base(int n, int t)` -> `int base()`, and then add `int n,t;` in the function body.

Comment: @wohlstad Sorry I'm a bit confused, I have learned that other than void, all functions should have an input, so wouldn't it be wrong if we declare int base() while we need an input? (I know compiler does error this, but I ask generally)

Comment: It is not mandatory that a function will have arguments. `int base()` is an example of a function that does **not** have any arguments (but returns an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

To print an ASCII code as a character, you cast it to char. So, instead of

```
cout << x[j];
```

You can do

```
cout << static_cast<char>(x[j]);
```

However, you currently leave digits below 10 as a number, which after casting to char would be wrong. You could fix that by adding '0' to rem if it's less than 10.

Another possibility is changing the type of x from int to char; that way, you wouldn't have to cast.